# Exception: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Trying to create a test for spark data streaming writeStream function as shown below:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("spark 
session").getOrCreate()

val lakeDF = spark.createDF(List(("hi")), List(("word", StringType, true)))

lakeDF.writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.Once)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
  .start(dataPath)
```

But I am getting following exception:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;

I am very new to spark streaming, please let me know how can i create a streaming dataframe/convert the above regular dataframe into streaming dataframe for my test suite.

Answer (score 6):

In Spark Structured Streaming dataframes/datasets are created out stream using **readStream** on SparkSession. If the dataframe/dataset are not created using stream then you are not allowed store using **writeStream**.

So create the dataframes/datasets using **readStream** and store the dataframes/datasets using **writeStream**

```
 val kafkaStream = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-broker-hostname:port")
.option("subscribe", "topicname")
.load()
```

Answer (score 3):

Only streaming dataframes can be written to streaming destination like queue etc.

For testing, spark streaming provides rate dataframes which can be used to create create mock streaming dataframes.

```py
rateDf = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("rate") \
        .option("numPartitions", 5) \
        .option("rowsPerSecond", 5) \
        .load()
```

One can add key-value data to above dataframe to create a streaming dataframe of your own mock data as below:

```py
rateDf = rateDf.\
    withColumn("key", randUdf()).\
    withColumn("value", mockDf.select("someCol"))
```

Comment: Reference docs for the rate inputSource: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources

Answer (score -3):

Consider the following examples.

First one works with df that is not streaming. like yours e.g. a file or a df made from a list/seq.

```
// Write key-value data from a DataFrame to a specific Kafka topic specified in an option
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic1")
  .save()
```

The second one works with dataframe that is streaming. e.g reading from kafka or some other streaming source.

```
// Write key-value data from a DataFrame to a specific Kafka topic specified in an option
val ds = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic1")
  .start()
```

either use a streaming dataframe or change your code like the first example.

Comment: Is there a way to create a streaming df with some hard coded values without using Kafka/ streaming frame work ?